# Cannot Disable Certificate Revocation on Internet Explorer (Expired Cert)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, webdriver

Apparently there is an expired certificate on a site that I use for automated testing with Selenium Webdriver. I've tried disabling the certificate revocation in Internet Settings, and restarting IE (as well as Windows, just to be safe), but to no avail.

I also tried using Webdriver to navigate past the warning page, but no success there either. For some reason it can't detect the "Continue" button on the page, either using xpath, or the built in "By.id" locating mechanism. I'm open to a WebDriver solution to this problem, but I would prefer a solution that allows me to disable certificate revocation. I don't use IE for anything else than automated testing on a VM, so I'm not concerned about security problems.

Just in case WebDriver is the only option, here is the source code of the page

```
<HTML dir=ltr><HEAD><TITLE>Certificate Error: Navigation Blocked</TITLE><LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="ErrorPageTemplate.css">
<META name=MS.LOCALE content=EN-US>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<META content=Yes http-equiv=MSThemeCompatible>
<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript src="errorPageStrings.js">
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript src="httpErrorPagesScripts.js">
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript src="invalidcert.js">
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY class=securityError onload="BodyLoad(); initMoreInfo('infoBlockID');">
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=730><!-- Main title -->
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD id=shieldIconAlign vAlign=top rowSpan=3 width=60 align=left><IMG id=shieldIcon alt="Shield icon" src="red_shield_48.png"> </TD>
<TD id=mainTitleAlign vAlign=center width=* align=left>
<H1 id=mainTitle>There is a problem with this website's security certificate.</H1></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<H3>
<DIV id=linkdiv name="linkdiv"></DIV></H3></TD></TR>
<TR><!-- This row is for the the divider-->
<TD id=errorCodeAlign class=errorCodeAndDivider align=right>&nbsp; 
<DIV class=divider></DIV></TD></TR><!-- Error Body -->
<TR>
<TD></TD>
<TD>
<H3>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=CertUnknownCA name="CertUnknownCA"></DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: block" id=CertExpired name="CertExpired">The security certificate presented by this website has expired or is not yet valid.</DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: block" id=CertCNMismatch name="CertCNMismatch">The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.</DIV>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=CertRevoked name="CertRevoked"></DIV><NOSCRIPT id=securityCert1></NOSCRIPT><BR><ID id=securityCert2>Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server.</ID> </H3></TD></TR><!-- Recommendation-->
<TR>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>
<H2 id=recommendation><B>We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website. </B></H2></TD></TR><!-- close webpage-->
<TR>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD id=closeWebpageAlign vAlign=center align=left>
<H4 id=closeWebpage><IMG class=actionIcon border=0 alt="Recommended icon" src="green_shield.png"><A href="javascript:closePage()">Click here to close this webpage.</A> </H4></TD></TR><!-- continue to site-->
<TR>
<TD>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD id=continueToSiteAlign vAlign=center align=left>
<H4 id=continueToSite><IMG id=ImgOverride class=actionIcon border=0 alt="Not recommended icon" src="red_shield.png"><A id=overridelink href="<href>" name=overridelink>Continue to this website (not recommended).</A> </H4></TD></TR><!-- InfoBlock -->
<TR>
<TD id=infoBlockAlign vAlign=top align=right>&nbsp; </TD>
<TD id=moreInformationAlign vAlign=center align=left>
<H4>
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=top><A onclick="javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true); return false;" href="#"><IMG id=infoBlockIDImage class=actionIcon border=0 alt="More information" src="down.png"></A> </TD>
<TD vAlign=top><SPAN id=moreInfoContainer><A href="javascript:expandCollapse('infoBlockID', true);">More information</A></SPAN><NOSCRIPT></NOSCRIPT></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></H4>
<DIV style="DISPLAY: none" id=infoBlockID class=infoBlock>
<P>
<LI id=errorExpl1>If you arrived at this page by clicking a link, check the website address in the address bar to be sure that it is the address you were expecting. 
<LI id=errorExpl2>When going to a website with an address such as https://example.com, try adding the 'www' to the address, https://www.example.com. 
<LI id=errorExpl3>If you choose to ignore this error and continue, do not enter private information into the website. 
<P></P>
<P id=moreInfoSeeHelpPF>For more information, see "Certificate Errors" in Internet Explorer Help.</P></LI></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

And here is what I tried (in Java):

```
ieDriver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();    
ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='overridelink']")).click();
ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//A[@id='overridelink']")).click();
```

Which I'm guessing doesn't work because the attribute value is not specified in quotes, so it's incorrect html.

I also tried this:

```
ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='<href>']")).click();
ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//A[@id='<href>']")).click();
```

Where

```
<href>
```

Symbolizes the actual URL.

I also was unable to locate surrounding tags using the same method.

Note: This also did not work for me: [Webdriver not finding elements in remote IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983184/webdriver-not-finding-elements-in-remote-ie)

I suspect because it doesn't alleviate security concerns to trust an expired certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one solution that works is just to create a new certificate with an acceptable end date. This works only if you have access to the server, permission from the administrator to do so, and don't mind signing your own certificate (at least temporarily). I don't really like this solution, but because it seems like a valid answer to my question, I'll just go with it. I'll create a new question related to WebDriver functionality specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an alert box that IE is creating you can try the `.SwitchTo()` I use it for alert boxes.

```
  WebDriver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks AJ, unfortunately it is an actual page. If it were an alert, that would certainly make it easier!